# Write a program to print the pattern for the given N number of rows

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

following pattern:

Sample Input 2 :

```
5
```

Sample Output 2 :

```
13579
35791
57913
79135
91357
```

my java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int i = 1;

        while(i<=n) {
            int j = 1;
            int odd = 1;

            while(j <= n) {
                System.out.print(odd);
                odd = odd+2;
                j++;
            }

            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, you've stated what you expected and you have your code, but, er, you seem to have forgotten an actual question.

Comment: What happens if the input is greater than 5 ? You need to provide correct input/output scenarios and also what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Sample Input 1 :
3
Sample Output 1 :
135
351
513     @Jasmeet

Comment: @Jasmeet i am not able to find an approach

Comment: @tejasvir what if n is greater than 5 ?

Comment: @jasmeet that was the only sample input i have what i observed is it would follow for sample input 6  sample output 1,3,5,7,9,11 /n 3 5 7 9 11 1 /n 5 7 9 11 1 3 and so on

Answer (score 1):

I just updated your code to correctly print the output you require.

Note that I have used array to store the odd numbers as per count rather than creating them every time. This will also be useful to keep track of the previous output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt(); // Get input number n
        
        int[] arr = new int[n]; // Array to store odd numbers
        int odd = 1; // Start of odd number
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        { // Store the odd numbers in array
            arr[i] = odd;
            odd += 2;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            PrintArray(arr,n); // Print array
            leftRotatebyOne(arr,n); // Rotate the array to left by one
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    static void leftRotatebyOne(int[] arr, int n) 
    { 
        int i, temp = arr[0]; 
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1]; 
  
        arr[i] = temp; 
    }
    
    static void PrintArray(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be what you're looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Open the scanner, set variables
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int add = 2, iterations = scanner.nextInt();

    // For the amount of times entered
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        // Again, for the amount of times entered
        for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++) {
            // j * add calculates what digit we are at right now. i *
            // add calculates the offset, so 1 becomes 3, or 5, or 7...
            int baseValue = j * add + i * add;
            // Calculates the max value for the amount of times entered: 5 times -> 10, 6
            // times -> 12...
            int max = iterations * add;
            // Prints the rest of dividing baseValue by max, plus one (to make the number
            // odd)
            System.out.print(baseValue % max + 1);
        }

        // Starts a new line
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Closes the scanner, which is good practice
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Calculation is overly complex. Just do `System.out.print((i + j) % iterations * 2 + 1);` No need for `add`, `baseValue`, or `max`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int i = 1;
        int maxOdd = 1+(n-1)*2;
        int oddCount =0;
        while(i<=n){
            int j =1;
            int odd=1;
            odd=odd+oddCount;
            while(j<=n){
                
                if(odd>maxOdd){
                     odd=1;
                }
                System.out.print(odd);
                odd=odd+2;
                j=j+1;
               
            }
            System.out.println();
            i=i+1;
            oddCount= oddCount+2;
            
        }
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int maxOdd = 1 + (n - 1) * 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int p = 2 * i - 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if (p > maxOdd) {
                    p = 1;
                }
                System.out.print(p);
                p = p + 2;
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // `Write your code here
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
       
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int p = 2 * i - 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                    System.out.print(p);
                    p = p + 2;
                 int maxOdd =(2*n)-1;
                 if(p>maxOdd){
                    p=1;
                }
               
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    s.close();
        
         

    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
**This is the easiest way that you are looking for**
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter rows : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int x;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                x = 2 * (i + j);
                if (i + j <= n + 1) {
                System.out.print(x - 3 + " ");
                } else {
                System.out.print(x - (n * 2 + 3) + " ");
                }
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation , it helps to understand for beginners as well as learner.